# C++ General Pointer Function or Template

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

How can I write a function that would be compatible either with vanilla pointer types (`T*`) or the special pointer types defined in `<memory>` such as `std::unique_ptr`?

I tried using the `std::is_pointer` check, but it looks like this is not the correct approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
void SomePointerFunction(
     T p, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type* = nullptr) {
  std::cout << (p ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int* p;
  std::unique_ptr<int> q;
  SomePointerFunction(p); // If we cange p to q, template matching fails

  return 0;
}
```

Is there some sort of general pointer type defined in C++ that could encapsulate these different types of pointers, or a different template check that would achieve this?

---

After thinking about it more, I also understand why this would actually be an undesirable feature of the language, because the two types of pointers are very different in many ways.  However, if you just want to write a function that utilizes the dereferencing property of pointers, it seems reasonable that this could be useful.  Is there some way to say "This function takes one argument, for which the operator `*` is defined"?

Comment: You might consider adding an overload `void SomePointerFunction(std::nullptr_t) { SomePointerFunction( static_cast<void*>(nullptr) ); }` since the `nullptr_t` type is not technically a pointer type and cannot be dereferenced, but is often expected to act like a pointer.

Comment: That seems quite reasonable in many contexts, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Do you want to handle also `std::nullptr_t` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some way to say "This function takes one argument, for which
>   the operator * is defined"?

There is, just *try to* dereference it. If it doesn't work, SFINAE kicks in:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(*std::declval<T>())>
```

We're using `std::declval` to get a `T`, dereference it and try to get the decltype. The end-result is ignored, we only need it to compile, which means `T` is dereferencable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename = decltype(*std::declval<T>())>
void SomePointerFunction(
     T& p) {
  std::cout << (p ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int* p = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<int> q;
  int i = 0;
  SomePointerFunction(p);
  SomePointerFunction(q);
  //SomePointerFunction(i);
  /* Above prints:
   main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
   main.cpp:16:24: error: no matching function for call to 'SomePointerFunction(int&)'
   */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SomePointerFunction` should probably not take a `T&` since it doesn't modify the argument. I'd use either just `T` or the forwarding reference `T&&`.

Comment: Awesome, this is actually sleeker than I expected.  I'll just have to read more on `decltype` and `declval` - these have always confused me, but I think that's because I haven't yet seen them in a compelling context (for me).

Comment: @aschepler I had to change it to `T&` since `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable, `T&&` might be a better choice though.

Comment: I'm wondering what the syntax `typename = <type>` means (in the second template parameter).  Is that an anonymous shorthand for `typename U = <type>`, where `<type>` would be the default type, and the name is not needed because it's not referenced elsewhere?

Comment: @Apollys, exactly.

Comment: Note that `SomePointerFunction(nullptr);` won't compile.

Comment: Note that this form of SFINAE would wrongly allow `SomePointerFunction<int, void>(i);`. `template<typename T> std::void_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>
void SomePointerFunction` would be fine for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 That doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: @Apollys: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1807468ee4a7fd5), but void_t is C++17, but can be implemented before.